# Rspec/Capybara not displaying expected results for cache_counter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara

The problem is the results printed to the screen by capybara/rspec are different to the values in the database.

Background 
 - I have a many-to-many relationship between promo and products. 
 - Promo has a products_counter column to keep track of the number of products related to a promo. This is handled with counter_cache on the association.
 - This functionality is working. I have tested it through the front end - basic crud functionality - and all the data is correct on the front end.

Something is happening and I can't figure it out. My spec fails because the page does not have the value '1' on it which is the product count. The page instead has 2 for the product count on the page.
 I thought that this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248194/rails-3-and-rspec-counter-cache-column-being-updated-to-2-when-expected-1) could be a point in the right direction, but I had no luck with that and there isn't much else on google.

See spec below.

```
require 'rails_helper'
include Warden::Test::Helpers
Warden.test_mode!

feature 'Promo index page' do
  scenario 'displays a list of promos' do
    admin = create(:user, :admin)
    p1 = create(:promo)
    p1.products << create(:product)

    login_as(admin)
    visit promos_path

    puts p1.products.count # => 1 in console
    puts p1.products_count # => 1 in console

    # save_and_open_page => this gives me a view into the page 
    # on the browser - lets me see that product count is printing 
    # to the screen as 2

    expect(page).to have_text p.code
    expect(page).to have_text p.name
    expect(page).to have_text p.products.count # => fails because page displays 2 instead of 1
  end
end
```

I have included the view for those that want to see how it's being rendered.

```
header.full-width-row  
  .columns.large-12
    = link_to 'New Promo', new_promo_path, class: 'right button tiny radius'

section.full-width-row
  .columns.large-12
    table.full-width
      thead
        tr
          td = "Code"
          td = "Name"
          td = "Product Count"
      tbody
        - @promos.each do |p|
          tr
            td.filter-on = p.code
            td.filter-on = link_to p.name, promo_path(p)
            td = p.products_count
```

Any help appreciated.